# C#/WPF - Shared Style Setters

Tags: c#, wpf, datatrigger, multidatatrigger, wpf-style

I'm trying to style a set of controls which display levels for a device.

I'm using a Label control that has a style with a multidata trigger which checks if the value of that field is between a certain value, and applies a highlight to indicate an error.

```
<Style x:Key="highlight-stat" TargetType="Label">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Value="True">
                    <Condition.Binding>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BetweenValuesConverter}">
                            <Binding/>
                            <Binding>
                                <Binding.Source>
                                    <sys:Int32>100</sys:Int32>
                                </Binding.Source>
                            </Binding>
                            <Binding>
                                <Binding.Source>
                                    <sys:Int32>200</sys:Int32>
                                </Binding.Source>
                            </Binding>
                            <Binding>
                                <Binding.Source>
                                    <sys:Boolean>True</sys:Boolean>
                                </Binding.Source>
                            </Binding>
                            <Binding>
                                <Binding.Source>
                                    <sys:Boolean>False</sys:Boolean>
                                </Binding.Source>
                            </Binding>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Condition.Binding>
                </Condition>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The issue I'm trying to tackle is that there are typically two or three states: normal, warning, and error. These states apply to multiple fields.

I want to be able to consolidate the setters of my trigger into a static resource which I can store separately, like a List, and simply use this list as the value for MultiDataTrigger.Setters. In this way, I can define my error and warning state as a collection of setters and update them from a central location.

IE:

```
<Style x:Key="error-state" TargetType="Control">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="warning-state" TargetType="Control">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
</Style>
```

The issue I'm having is DataTrigger/MultiDataTrigger's Setters property has no set method, and the trigger is required to determine the state.

Is there any way I can accomplish what I want?

Possible solutions:

- a control that accepts a list of ranges, and applies the correct style
- copy/paste the setters from one trigger to another ***currently using this***
- @PieterWitvoet recommended `StyleSelector`

**EDIT**

I've created a user control to accomplish what I want.
C#

```
public class Label : System.Windows.Controls.Label, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Label()
    {
        var metadata = ContentProperty.GetMetadata(this);
        ContentProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Label), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(propertyChanged));

        Rules = new List<HighlightingRule>();
        PropertyChanged += (o, a) =>
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("#triggered - {0}", a.PropertyName));
        };
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the highlighting rules applied by this control
    /// </summary>
    public List<HighlightingRule> Rules { get; set; }

    static void propertyChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (o is Label)
        {
            (o as Label).reapplyRules();
        }
    }


    void reapplyRules()
    {
        Style = null;
        foreach (var rule in Rules)
        {
            if (rule.IsMatch(Content))
            {
                Style = rule.MatchStyle;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using the below base class to define rules

```
/// <summary>
/// Base Class for Highlighting rules used by HighlightedLabel
/// </summary>
public abstract class HighlightingRule
{
    public Style MatchStyle { get; set; }

    public virtual bool IsMatch(object value)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

For example:

```
public class UnderValueRule : HighlightingRule
{
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public bool Inclusive { get; set; }

    public override bool IsMatch(object value)
    {
        if (value is int || value is double)
        {
            double dValue = Convert.ToDouble(value);
            return dValue.CompareTo(Value) <= (Inclusive ? 0 : -1);
        }
        else if (value is decimal)
        {
            decimal dValue = Convert.ToDecimal(value);
            return dValue.CompareTo(Convert.ToDecimal(Value)) <= (Inclusive ? 0 : -1);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

In XAML:

```
<rules:UnderValueRule Value="31" Inclusive="False" MatchStyle="{StaticResource error-state}"/>
```

Comment: Apparently some people use converters for this - so you'd write a custom `IValueConverter` that determines which style is appropriate for which range. For item controls you can also use a `StyleSelector`. So instead of a single style with different sets of setters, you'll have some logic that selects one of several styles.

Comment: Interesting. Inherit from StyleSelector and go from there, correct? This solution would require a new class per predicate, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Parameterize the differences and you only need a new instance per predicate. Keep in mind that you can set properties on converters in XAML. Your `BetweenValuesConverter` could've been a single-value converter: `<my:RangeConverter x:Key="Between100And200Converter" From="100" To="200" Between="True" Outside="False" />`. An alternative that I would probably look into would be to let your view-model determine the status and expose that as an extra property. That should make it more obvious what's going on and the view can be kept simpler.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet,I forgot I could add properties to my ValueConverters. However, I am passing them like this as a IMultiValueConverter is because the BetweenValuesConverter is reused multiple times. I've ended up creating a control that accepts a list of constraints and applies a style. I couldn't work out how to pass a predicate to a StyleSelector.